# Spring boot Invalid UUID string: a; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: a

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

Hi I have a bug on app spring when I execute the call reported in this point I have the following error, what is it due to and how can I fix it?
**Error:**

```
Invalid UUID string: a; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: a
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) 
    ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
```

**First.java:**

```
@Component
public class GLTransactionQuery extends JpaQuery<GLTransaction, GLTransactionRepository> {

  public Page<GLTransaction> getPagedGLTransactions(
      Integer page, Integer size, String order, String[] columns, String search) {
    return findAllByPage(page, size, order, columns, search);
  }
}
```

**Second.java:**

```
   protected Page<D> findAllByPage(Integer page, Integer size, String order, String[] columns, String search) {
        PageRequest pr = createPageRequest(page, size, order, columns);
        return Strings.isNullOrEmpty(search) ? this.repository.findAll(pr) : this.repository.findAll(this.getSearchSpecification(search), pr);
    }
```